# How to build OpenJDK 11 from sources for aarch64?

Tags: java, java-11, arm64

I have qemu with ARM64 debian which is installed this way:

download https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/arm64/iso-cd/debian-11.1.0-arm64-netinst.iso

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-arm
sudo apt-get install qemu-efi-aarch64
sudo apt-get install qemu-utils
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash1.img bs=1M count=64
dd if=/dev/zero of=flash0.img bs=1M count=64
dd if=/usr/share/qemu-efi-aarch64/QEMU_EFI.fd of=flash0.img conv=notrunc
qemu-img create ubuntu-image.img 20G
qemu-system-aarch64 -nographic -machine virt,gic-version=max -m 3G -cpu max -smp 4 \
-netdev user,id=vnet,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:0-:22 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=vnet \
-drive file=ubuntu-image.img,if=none,id=drive0,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive0,bootindex=0 \
-drive file=debian-11.1.0-arm64-netinst.iso,if=none,id=drive1,cache=writeback -device virtio-blk,drive=drive1,bootindex=1 \
-drive file=flash0.img,format=raw,if=pflash -drive file=flash1.img,format=raw,if=pflash
```

I need to build on this emulator the following openjava fork https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/tree/master/ for that I installed JDK 15 on qemu-aarch64-debian and build fails:

```
    katya@debian:~/openjdk$ ./configure
... sucess 
...
katya@debian:~/openjdk$ make images

    Building target 'images' in configuration 'linux-aarch64-normal-server-release'
    Compiling 8 files for BUILD_TOOLS_LANGTOOLS
    Parsing 2 properties into enum-like class for jdk.compiler
    Compiling 19 properties into resource bundles for jdk.compiler
    Compiling 13 properties into resource bundles for jdk.javadoc
    Creating hotspot/variant-server/tools/adlc/adlc from 13 file(s)
    Compiling 2 files for BUILD_JVMTI_TOOLS
    Compiling 1 files for BUILD_JFR_TOOLS
    Compiling 12 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jdeps
    Compiling 7 properties into resource bundles for jdk.jshell
    Compiling 117 files for BUILD_java.compiler.interim
    Compiling 394 files for BUILD_jdk.compiler.interim
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/file/JavacFileManager.java:516: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                    this.fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archivePath, null);
                                                 ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/file/Locations.java:385: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                                FileSystems.newFileSystem(file, null).close();
                                           ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/platform/JDKPlatformProvider.java:113: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(ctSymFile, null);
                                                ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/platform/JDKPlatformProvider.java:252: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                            ctSym2FileSystem.put(file, fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(file, null));
                                                                       ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    4 errors
    gmake[3]: *** [CompileInterimLangtools.gmk:89: /home/katya/openjdk/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/buildtools/interim_langtools_modules/jdk.compiler.interim/_the.BUILD_jdk.compiler.interim_batch] Error 1
    gmake[2]: *** [make/Main.gmk:76: interim-langtools] Error 2
    gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    
    ERROR: Build failed for target 'images' in configuration 'linux-aarch64-normal-server-release' (exit code 2) 
    
    === Output from failing command(s) repeated here ===
    * For target buildtools_interim_langtools_modules_jdk.compiler.interim__the.BUILD_jdk.compiler.interim_batch:
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/file/JavacFileManager.java:516: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                    this.fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(archivePath, null);
                                                 ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/file/Locations.java:385: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                                FileSystems.newFileSystem(file, null).close();
                                           ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/platform/JDKPlatformProvider.java:113: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(ctSymFile, null);
                                                ^
      both method newFileSystem(Path,ClassLoader) in FileSystems and method newFileSystem(Path,Map<String,?>) in FileSystems match
    /home/katya/openjdk/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/platform/JDKPlatformProvider.java:252: error: reference to newFileSystem is ambiguous
                            ctSym2FileSystem.put(file, fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(file, null));
                                                                       ^
       ... (rest of output omitted)
    
    * All command lines available in /home/katya/openjdk/build/linux-aarch64-normal-server-release/make-support/failure-logs.
    === End of repeated output ===
    
    No indication of failed target found.
    Hint: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
    Hint: See doc/building.html#troubleshooting for assistance.
    
    make[1]: *** [/home/katya/openjdk/make/Init.gmk:305: main] Error 2
    make: *** [/home/katya/openjdk/make/Init.gmk:186: images] Error 2
```

This is because the build MUST use JDK 9 or 10 but I have forced configs to accept Java 15, which gave me the following error https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223197
But there is no JDK 9,10 for ARM64 !!!! The ARM64 support starts from Java 15! The question is - how to build from sources OpenJava for aarch64 architecture on linux??

Comment: I suggest downloading a prebuild from [adoptopenjdk](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html). They have prebuilds for Java 9, 10, ... and aarch64 architecture.

Comment: Did you read [building.md](https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/blob/master/doc/building.md#building-on-armaarch64)? Maybe it helps.

Comment: @gthanop There is cross-compiling section which mention "bash configure --with-devkit=<devkit-path> --openjdk-target=ppc64-linux-gnu && make" but I do not understand what is <devkit-path> and how to get it

Comment: I think you read the correct section, but not thoroughly. In [this](https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/blob/master/doc/building.md#cross-compiling-the-easy-way-with-openjdk-devkits) section it states *Devkits can be created from the make/devkit directory* and if you look at the repository there is indeed [such location](https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/tree/master/make/devkit). Instructions on how to build a *Devkit* are also in the same building.md's section.

Comment: @gthanop └─$ make aarch64-linux-gnu
Error: No configurations found for /home/katya/work/prostor/openjdk.
Please run 'bash configure' to create a configuration.

Comment: Seems like you first need to run [`configure`](https://gitlab.com/gosjava/11/openjdk/-/blob/master/doc/building.md#running-configure). Reading the whole *building.md* in detail and in a sequential manner should make the build process succeed, so please be patient and go ahead read it starting from the beggining.